# high charts from csv not drawing the chart on refresh page

Tags: csv, highcharts, refresh

I have created a `highchart` and data I took it from csv file.The chart is working good and plotting fine.But my problem is when the page refreshes it is not taking the latest value from the csv file.It still displays the old chart.when I close the browser and re-open the chart works fine.Please help me how to reset/redraw with updated value from csv Below is my code. This problem is happening in IE not in firefox. If I right click the displayed chart and export to excel then its showing updated value but not drawing the chart with updated value.

```
  <html> 
  <head>

  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" /> 
   <LINK  REL="StyleSheet" HREF="../style/default.css" TYPE="text/css"
 MEDIA="screen">        
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>        
  <script type="text/javascript"  src="../js/highcharts.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {      
                 cache:false
                 var options="";
         options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                defaultSeriesType: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Incident Status'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis:

            {
             allowDecimals:false, tickInterval:15,
                title: {
                    text: 'Issue Count'
                }
            },
            series: []          
          };

        /*
         Load the data from the CSV file. This is the contents of the file:

            Apples,Pears,Oranges,Bananas,Plums
            John,8,4,6,5
            Jane,3,4,2,3
            Joe,86,76,79,77
            Janet,3,16,13,15

         */             $.get('../data/incident_status.txt', function(data) {
            // Split the lines
            var lines = data.split(';');
            $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                var items = line.split(',');

                // header line containes categories
                if (lineNo == 0) {
                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                        if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                    });
                }

                // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
                else {
                    var series;

                    series= {
                        data: [],
                        pointWidth: 28

                    };
                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                        if (itemNo == 0) {
                            series.name = item;
                        } else {

                            series.data.push(parseFloat(item)); 

                        }
                    });
                options.series.push(series);
                }
            });

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            chart.destroy();

                        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);          
       });


    });         </script>

    <body>
                        <div id="wrapper">
                            <div  class="container">

                        <div id="banner" >
                            <div class="img-border"> <img src="../images/logo.jpg" width="1120" height="111px" alt="" /> </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

                        <?php include('../control/incidentstatus_gen.php');?>

                            </div>

                        </div>



<body> </html>
```

Comment: Are you getting new data on refresh from your `$.get` ?

Comment: no if i press f5 it is not refreshing.If i close the browser and re-open it then its working. this problem only happening in IE.

Answer (score 1):

It looks lie the $.gt is getting the file from browser cache. The way round this is to ,are the request unique by adding a variable parameter. Jquery can help you

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

Or you can do it yourself by adding a date time parameter to make the request unique.

```
$.get(filename,{ "_": $.now() }, function(data){
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you vermuch guys.The problem fixed.It was a browser settings issue.I change the setting to load cache each time the page refreshes.now its working

Comment: That's fine for your browser, but won't work for other people who don't have the correct browser settings.

Comment: yes you are right.mine is just a display to the user so no issue. But if it is hosting it in web then it is a issue.Highcharts has to fix it

Comment: It's not a highcharts issue. It's to do with using jquery to make ajax calls, and making sure it forces the browser to not use cached data.

Comment: Above answer is proper. You should use $.ajax() instead of $.get() and set cache: false.